# Go back Through Action Bar from Fragment To Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-actionbar

I want to Put One back Button on Action Bar And After clicking on that I want to go back to an Activity. I am Writing Following code , but  i am not able to achieve the same. Please Help me. Thnks

```
   public class NutrientDailyTrackerActivity extends Fragment {



 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_nutrient_details, container, false);  
    ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();

    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#4CC1D2")));
    actionBar.setTitle("Nutrient Tracker");
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                 // doing some task here

    }



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CalorieMainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragment is hosted inside an `Activity`. And `ActionBar` is too hosted in an `Activity`. So, you should write this thing inside the `Activity` where you are hosting the `ActionBar`.

Put the code of `Actionbar` inside `onCreate` of `Activity` where fragment is hosted. And don't forget to move the code of back button click handler to `Activity` too.